# How to change the background image of an activity at regular interval in android?

Tags: android, image, background

I want to change the background image of the activity after every 30 seconds in android.

Does anyone know, how to accomplish this?

Thanks in Advance,
-Neha

Comment: Use Timer to do this. See here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612579/call-particular-method-after-regular-interval-of-time/4612602#4612602

Comment: Hi Vikas, is there any special way to accept the answers? Do i have to send any mail or click on any link to accept the answers?

Comment: click the checkmark under the vote next to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using a Handler. The Android developer guide has some information on how to [update the UI using a timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html). Hope you find this useful!

Comment: Hey Sam, Thanks a lot for ur answer. I'll try it and will let u know :)

Comment: Hi Neha. No problem! I would also reccommend trying the method linked by Vikas!

Comment: Hey Sam, the link that Vikas gave will be useful to display the same image at regular interval of time. But how to change that image?

Comment: Resources can be accessed at runtime by the guidelines here: (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html). That link also shows to to set the image of an ImageView using the setImageResource(int resId) method. Simply setting this and passing a new resource ID should do the trick.

Comment: If you believe that an answer has answered your question, make sure to mark it as an answer. That will up that score :)

Comment: On the answer you want to mark as 'the answer', click the tick on left under the vote arrows

Comment: Ohhhh :) Thanks a lot Sam :) I was not knowing that at all and you see so many people criticized me for that :P. Thanks a lot :)